# How to start the fading in/out from the current fading point and not starting over again the fading it self?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The fading in/out script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Description : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas canvas;
    public AnimationCurve animationCurve;
    public float fadingSpeed = 5f;
    
    public TMP_InputField _inputField;

    public enum Direction { FadeIn, FadeOut };

    private CanvasGroup canvasGroup;

    void Start()
    {
        if (canvas == null) canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
        canvasGroup = canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        if (canvasGroup == null) Debug.LogError("Please assign a canvas group to the canvas!");

        if (animationCurve.length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Animation curve not assigned: Create a default animation curve");
            animationCurve = AnimationCurve.EaseInOut(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
        }
    }

    public float StartFading(bool InOut)
    {
        if (canvasGroup != null)
        {
            if (InOut)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FadeCanvas(canvasGroup, Direction.FadeIn, fadingSpeed));
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(FadeCanvas(canvasGroup, Direction.FadeOut, fadingSpeed));
            }
        }

        return fadingSpeed;
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeCanvas(CanvasGroup canvasGroup, Direction direction, float duration)
    {
        // keep track of when the fading started, when it should finish, and how long it has been running
        var startTime = Time.time;
        var endTime = Time.time + duration;
        var elapsedTime = 0f;

        // set the canvas to the start alpha – this ensures that the canvas is ‘reset’ if you fade it multiple times
        if (direction == Direction.FadeIn) canvasGroup.alpha = animationCurve.Evaluate(0f);
        else canvasGroup.alpha = animationCurve.Evaluate(1f);

        // loop repeatedly until the previously calculated end time
        while (Time.time <= endTime)
        {
            elapsedTime = Time.time - startTime; // update the elapsed time
            var percentage = 1 / (duration / elapsedTime); // calculate how far along the timeline we are
            if ((direction == Direction.FadeOut)) // if we are fading out
            {
                canvasGroup.alpha = animationCurve.Evaluate(1f - percentage);
            }
            else // if we are fading in/up
            {
                canvasGroup.alpha = animationCurve.Evaluate(percentage);
            }

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // wait for the next frame before continuing the loop
        }

        // force the alpha to the end alpha before finishing – this is here to mitigate any rounding errors, e.g. leaving the alpha at 0.01 instead of 0
        if (direction == Direction.FadeIn) canvasGroup.alpha = animationCurve.Evaluate(1f);
        else canvasGroup.alpha = animationCurve.Evaluate(0f);

        if (_inputField != null)
        {
            _inputField.readOnly = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then using with HoverEnter and HoverOut methods to make the fading in/out.
both method i'm calling in the editor through ui button trigger events : pointer enter and pointer exit.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class ButtonHover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Description description;
    public TextMeshProUGUI descriptionText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        descriptionText.text = "";
    }

    public void HoverEnter()
    {
        string savedGamesFolder = string.Format("{0}/Saved Screenshots",
            Application.persistentDataPath);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(savedGamesFolder);
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dirs[i].Contains(gameObject.name))
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirs[i]);
                if (files.Length == 3)
                {
                    string allText = File.ReadAllText(files[0]);
                    descriptionText.text = allText;
                    description.StartFading(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    description.StartFading(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void HoverOut()
    {
        description.StartFading(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is if i'm moving the mouse cursor too fast while it's fading in then it's starting fade out but the text inside getting like the fading in finished but i changed it in the middle so the fading out should "start"(continue) from the current fading point.

I want the fading out to continue from the current fading point and to fade out from the start.

In both cases when the StartFading is false :

```
description.StartFading(false);
```

if the fading in is not finished yet then when fading out continue from the current fading in point and don't start fading out from the begining.

Comment: Why not just create your own fading script where you alter the gameObjects alpha value by Time.DeltaTime in the Update method? This way, you can save the current alpha value, set it back to 1 (or 0) and continue from where you left off later.

Comment: I believe this issue becomes trivial when using intervals instead of using set time values.  Interval in this case would be `Time.deltaTime / duration`.  Then you increase value `t` by interval.  If the routine is stopped in the middle, save `t` and start over from there later.  The "percentage" value is simply `t`.  Also, to wait until the next frame, use `yield return null;`